# Get Quote ID from an Order ID or Order Number SQL?

Tags: database, mysql, sales-quote

I need to query the Magento MySQL database to get an image path/name for a file.

What I have:

- Order ID
- Order Number

What I need:

- I need to get the image name/path from this table `sales_flat_quote_item_option`

From what I can see so far following the foreign keys that lead to this table.  I seem none of them use the order ID or order number as they all descend from the `sales_flat_quote` table instead of the `sales_flat_order` table.

---

Does anyone know of a fancy query I could use to get a value from the `sales_flat_quote_item_option` table by using what I have, order ID and number?

If I can simply get the `Quote ID` from my Order ID/Number then I can doing a join SQL query using the Quote ID to get my record from the `sales_flat_quote_item_option` table.

I have to do this with SQL instead of Magento Models as it will be ran outside of Magento in a separate application.

Comment: You should be able to use the quote_id from the `sales_flat_order` table to get the Quote ID you need

Comment: @CCBlackburn thanks I overlooked that existing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only one relation between  *Magento quote item tables & sales order tables*  and  that  is ***sales_flat_order.quote_id=sales_flat_quote_item.quote_id.***

In magento,`sales_flat_quote_item_option` does not have any direct relation with  `sales_flat_order`.It have an indirection relation

*`sales_flat_order.quote_id=sales_flat_quote.quote_id`*=> *`sales_flat_quote_item.item_id=sales_flat_quote_item_option.item_id`*

**Query seem like:**

```
SELECT * FROM sales_flat_quote_item_option where item_id in (
        select item_id from  sales_flat_quote_item  where quote_id in (
            SELECT quote_id FROM sales_flat_order  where entity_id =ORDER_ID

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks I cant remeber how I got past my issue as it was about a month ago however this may help me in the future or help someone else.  I just ran the SQL to do quick test and it seems to work!  SO thanks for sharing and hope it helps others too

Comment: PS) my own question confuses me as im not working in Magento for a month so amazing work!